# How to add a neural network model with ML models in VotingRegressor?

Tags: keras, regression, valueerror, ensemble-learning, voting

**Background of the Problem**

I was trying to use a `KerasRegressor` model with the ML models  (e.g. Lasso, Gradient Boost Regressor) for the purpose of building an ensemble method. I used the `VotingRegressor()` function of sklearn to group the models. However, when I add the `KerasRegressor` model in `VotingRegressor()`, I get the following error.

> ValueError: The estimator KerasRegressor should be a regressor.

**How Did I Try to Solve the Problem?**

I searched on google by the error and I found only [this page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36074) where I do not find the solution. Moreover, I tried to understand the [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/KerasRegressor) of the `KerasRegressor`. However, I do not know why I get the error as the document says that *it is the implementation of the scikit-learn regressor API for Keras*.

**Then, My Question**

Why did I get the error and what can I do to solve it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated :). Thanks!

Comment: i checked the github issue and found only 3rd party package as solution

Comment: Thank you Yefet. Yes, I also think that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/36137#issuecomment-726271760) there is no solution using keras as sklearn wrapper is not maintained and will be removed

Fortunately [scikeras](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/) package solve this issue.

I advice you to read docs or [tutorials](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/notebooks/Basic_Usage.html) but here a simple example using subclassing:

```
!pip install scikeras

import scikeras
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

class MLPRegressor(KerasRegressor):

    def __init__(
        self,
        hidden_layer_sizes=(100, ),
        optimizer="adam",
        optimizer__learning_rate=0.001,
        epochs=10,
        verbose=0,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.hidden_layer_sizes = hidden_layer_sizes
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.verbose = verbose

    def _keras_build_fn(self, compile_kwargs):
        model = keras.Sequential()
        inp = keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.n_features_in_))
        model.add(inp)
        for hidden_layer_size in self.hidden_layer_sizes:
            layer = keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation="relu")
            model.add(layer)
        out = keras.layers.Dense(1)
        model.add(out)
        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=compile_kwargs["optimizer"])
        return model

# simple linear regression
r1 = LinearRegression()
# keras model wrapper
r2= MLPRegressor(epochs=20)  


X = (y/2).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.arange(100)

#defining votting classifier
vr = VotingRegressor([('lr', r1), ('MLPReg', r2)])

vr.fit(X,y)
```

> VotingRegressor(estimators=[('lr',
> LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True,
> n_jobs=None, normalize=False)),
> ('MLPReg',
> MLPRegressor(batch_size=None, build_fn=None, callbacks=None, epochs=20, hidden_layer_sizes=(100,),
> loss=None, metrics=None, model=None, optimizer='adam',
> random_state=None, run_eagerly=False, shuffle=True,
> validation_batch_size=None, validation_split=0.0, verbose=0,
> warm_start=False))],
> n_jobs=None, weights=None)

Comment: Hi Yefet, thank you so much. `MLPRegressor` works like a charm. However, I do not get my answer why _`KerasRegressor` does not work?_ :)

Comment: it does not work as addressed in the issue that KerasRegressor doesn't have attribute of '_estimator_type'

Comment: Hi, could you update the docs link for Scikeras to https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/ ? thanks!

Comment: @LoveToCode Done! and also thankyou for creathing this package